# Wordpress Show list in thumbnails

Tags: css, wordpress, list

For my website: http://lovebet.ro
In homepage, the thumbnail post it doesnt show the text into a buletted list, the same way it looks when I enter the post: http://lovebet.ro/?p=47. Why's that?

I mention that the theme admin supports Custom CSS "Here you can add custom css to override or extend default styles."

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer.

Cheers
M

Comment: The text you want to show in bullet lists are surrounded with `<p />` tags you should change it to `<ul><li></li></ul>` and apply css rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahil for your fast response..but unfortunately I'm a noob in css. In Wordpress text editor (before posting) I already done what you said but I have no idea how to apply a "css rule".

Answer (score 0):

It's that the formatting gets removed when wordpress is pulling the_excerpt();. You can pull the_content(); instead if it won't cause problems in the future with having the whole content on the post previews. Go into the files for your category template and replace the call to the_excerpt(); with one to the_content(); .

See more solutions [here](http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/).

Comment: Cant I do something just altering the theme code? (not the entire WP)

Comment: This is in the theme code, probably index.php, home.php, category.php, or archive.php. The formatting is actually removed on the homepage, so you'd have to somehow re-make the list... I don't think you can do it without touching some part of the files.

[This gives a possible solution too](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/) but you have to get into functions.php.

Comment: Tried but..no result. I'm lost here.